# Data strucutre in JAva with SAME index number keys unless values are different

Tags: java, data-structures

I have some values (a , a , b , c , f , f , g) which I want to store in a **unique index based Data structure**, which I can later iterate over to get my values. However, if the values are same the index number MUST also be the same.

Can any one please let me know which is the simplest way ?

E.g

```
1 a
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 f
4 f
5 g
LATER,
```

Iterate on the DATA STRUCTURE based upon, the INDEX, to get my values

Comment: Smells like homework...

Comment: Looks like a map of lists. Or you can create your own class with key-value pairs and add instances of that class to a list.

Comment: Seems you need a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Or maybe a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). After all it's not very clear what exactly you need.

Comment: Have a look at [hashtables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: `1 a 1 a` 2 b 3 c 4 f 4 f 5 g ?. There can be only one index for one position. Unless you are asking for a map which allows duplicate keys and values, you are running out of luck. @user3580294 - A set with 2 indices  populated with the same value?

Comment: Lol !! This is not a home work. SMall part of a big project

Comment: @TheLostMind That was a complete guess on my part. I was assuming that what OP had was the input values + their resulting indices, but I have to admit it might not make sense...

Answer (score 0):

The usual idiom for such a data structure is

```
Map<Integer,Pair> int2pair
```

where

```
class Pair {
    int count;
    char value; // a, b, c
}
```

If the index values truly are index values, use

```
List<Pair> pairs
```

possibly backed up by a map

```
Map<Char,Integer> value2index
```

for faster lookup of the index by its value.

Much depends on things you haven't told us, such as the volume, is one index possible with different values as well, will the same value appear with different index values, frequency of retrieval accesses and how...

Comment: I don't think map would be an appropriate solution here. In fact I don't think there *ought* to be a solution for this... `1 a 1 a` 2 b 3 c `4 f 4 f` 5 g.. duplicate keys + duplicate values + index?. How would his *index* requirement fit in here?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly,

Then [Hashing with separate chaining](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/) will be one of the possible solutions

[image]

Here's the [complete solution](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/SeparateChainingHashST.java.html)